# AJAX con IF ELSE en la respuesta

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas estoy utilizando un AJAX para que los clientes se registren en la web y ahora le he añadido un query para saber si este usuario ya a sido registrado, paso a detallar como o estoy haciendo:

El `AJAX`

```
     <script>
      $(function(){
          $("#formuploadajax1").on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var f = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax1"));
              formData.append("dato", "valor");
              //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
              $.ajax({
                  url: "incluCuenta/insertar-cliente.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false
              })
                  .done(function(res){
                    if(res=="1"){
                        toastr["info"]("Registro exitoso!", "Mensaje")
                             setTimeout(function () {
                             window.location.href = "login.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                         }, 1500); //will call the function after 2 secs
                    }else{
                        $("#mensaje").html(res);
                        toastr["info"]("Utiliza otro usuario!", "Mensaje")
                    }
                  });
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Aqui el `insertar-cliente`

```
<?php include "../conexion/conexion.php" ?>
<?php

    mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
    $results = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
    $rec = mysqli_query($mysqli, $results);
    $verificar_usuario = 0;

    while($results = mysqli_fetch_object($rec))
    {
        if($results->Username == $_POST['email'])
        {
            $verificar_usuario = 1;

        }
    }

    if($verificar_usuario == 0)
    {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $movil = $_POST['movil'];
    $nif = $_POST['nif'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $postal = $_POST['postal'];
    $poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
    $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $fecha=date('y,m,d');



$results = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (Fecha, Sexo, Nombre, Password, Username, Direccion, Postal, Poblacion, Provincia, Telefono, Movil, Dni, intestado) 
VALUES ('$fecha', '$sexo', '$name', '$pass', '$email', '$direccion', '$postal', '$poblacion', '$provincia', '$telefono', '$movil', '$nif', '1')";

if ( !mysqli_query($mysqli, $results)) {
  die( 'Error: ' . mysqli_error() );
   }


   }

    else
    {
        echo '<span class="error">Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.</span>';
    }

?>
```

Lo que me falla es que el ajax me notifica, pero necesito que me notifique si esta repetido el Usuario hace un respuesta y si es correcto es la otra respuesta, algo tengo hecho pero no funciona bien.
Si esta ocupado el usuario sale el cartel de este usuario ya esta y no lo inserta en la bd, pero si esta todo correcto me muestra solo el toast contrario y si lo mete en la bd.

Comment: No tengo claro por qué te está guardando el usuario ya que parece que, si la variable $verificar_usuario se pone a 1 no debería entrar en la parte del insert. Comprueba que, efectivamente, esa variable tiene valor 1 después del bucle

Comment: No se muy bien como comprobar eso, pero las funciones las hace bien, es el notificar lo que no hace bien, seguro que he escrito algo mal

Comment: Otra cosa es que el código se puede mejorar mucho, no solo a nivel de formateo sino también, por ejemplo, añadiendo la condición en la consulta que compruebe si existe algún usuario con ese email (WHERE Username = $_POST['email']. Ten cuidado con las comillas y con los posibles valores que puedan venir en el campo email para evitar la inyeccion por sql

Comment: Soy bastante nuevo en esto, de ahi los fallos que veras en el código!

Comment: Para ver qué valor tiene la variable, pon lo siguiente después del bucle: var_dump($verificar_usuario); die();

Comment: Tranquilo, todos tenemos errores en el código, aun a pesar de llevar muchos años. Lo que te he dicho son consejos para mejorar

Comment: Lo se, aun queda muchisimo por aprender, pero bueno me encanta lo que hago y da gusto equivocarse :)

Comment: Si el usuario esta repetido me sale un "1" por lo contrario me sale un "0"

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos si el campo `Username` está definido en la tabla como clave única?

Comment: Nop, no es clave unica!

Comment: ¿No normalizas los nombres de usuario para impedir el registro del usuario `Oscar` y `oscar` (por poner un ejemplo) como usuarios diferentes? Como tienes reputación suficiente voy a tratar de pasar esta conversación a un chat para continuar en él.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82858/discussion-between-miguel-and-oscargarcia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parte de los errores sintácticos y de programación que he detectado, me he fijado que en ningún momento has devuelto el número "1" que espera recibir la petición XHR lanzada desde javascript. Esto impide que tu código funcione correctamente si se registra el usuario en la base de datos.

Por otro lado, el segundo error más grave que he encontrado ha sido la concatenación de cadenas sin escapar a una consulta SQL. Esto provoca que tu consulta falle si algún campo tiene una comilla en su interior o, peor aún, puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Para solucionarlo podemos hacer uso de consultas preparadas o bien usar [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) (como he hecho, así no tengo que hacerte muchas modificaciones en el código) para escapar previamente el contenido de la variable.

He dejado comentarios por el código para explicas las modificaciones que he hecho y los errores que he detectado:

```
<?php
/* Aquí olvidaste el ; del final */
include "../conexion/conexion.php";

/* Aquí olvidaste poner como primer parámetro la conexión mysqli */
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
$results = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
$rec = mysqli_query($mysqli, $results);
/* Si falló la consulta informamos de ello */
if ($rec === false) {
    die('ERROR SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)));
}
while ($results = mysqli_fetch_object($rec)) {
    /* Hacemos una comparación en minúsculas (si quieres) */
    if(mb_strtolower($results->Username) == mb_strtolower($_POST['email'])) {
        /* No es necesario marcar y luego comprobar, podemos finalizar aquí mismo */
        die('<span class="error">Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.</span>');
    }
}

/* Escapamos las cadenas correctamente para evitar tanto inyección SQL
    como cadenas mal formadas */
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
$telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['telefono']);
$movil = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['movil']);
$nif = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nif']);
$direccion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['direccion']);
$postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['postal']);
$poblacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['poblacion']);
$provincia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['provincia']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pass']);
$sexo = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sexo']);
/* Te aconsejo fechas en formato YYYY-MM-DD, localiza sólo al mostrar */
$fecha = date('y,m,d');

$results = "
    INSERT INTO Usuarios (
        Fecha,
        Sexo,
        Nombre,
        Password,
        Username,
        Direccion,
        Postal,
        Poblacion,
        Provincia,
        Telefono,
        Movil,
        Dni,
        intestado
    ) VALUES (
        '$fecha',
        '$sexo',
        '$name',
        '$pass',
        '$email',
        '$direccion',
        '$postal',
        '$poblacion',
        '$provincia',
        '$telefono',
        '$movil',
        '$nif',
        '1'
    )
";
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $results) === false) {
    /* Aquí olvidaste poner como primer parámetro la conexión mysqli */
    die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)));
}
/* Si todo ha ido bien tu aplicación espera encontrar el texto "1" */
echo "1";
```